# parse.com special characters in external csv file are not correctly encoded in Parse DB

Tags: csv, parse-platform, character-encoding

I am loading a external CSV file through parse.com and save the records in DB. Unfortunately the special characters are not correctly saved in Parse.

```
Example field from record in CSV: 
"wendbarer Gürtel aus Leder und GG Supreme"

 Same field in Parse DB:
 "wendbarer GÃ¼rtel aus Leder und GG Supreme"
```

Do you have any idea how this could happen??

Comment: please update if you found a solution or workaround! I tried in js: `unescape(encodeURIComponent(string))` to no avail.